# NullPointerException while deleting item from hazelcast queue

Tags: java, events, nullpointerexception, queue, hazelcast

I have the following code:

```
       hazelcastInstance.<Void>getQueue(UserStorageService.LOGOUT_ALL_USERS_QUEUE_NAME).addItemListener(new ItemListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void itemAdded(ItemEvent<Void> item) {
                //process event logic
                hazelcastInstance.<Void>getQueue(UserStorageService.LOGOUT_ALL_USERS_QUEUE_NAME).remove(item.getItem());
            }

            @Override
            public void itemRemoved(ItemEvent<Void> item) {
            }
        }, false);
```

I just send signal and here I process this signal.

I am a bit confising should I delete event after his processing ? I do it to avoid queue overflow but I  am not sure has it sense or not.

I ask this question because in logs I see following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Object is null
        at com.hazelcast.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:59)
        at com.hazelcast.collection.impl.queue.QueueProxySupport.checkObjectNotNull(QueueProxySupport.java:166)
        at com.hazelcast.collection.impl.queue.QueueProxySupport.removeInternal(QueueProxySupport.java:128)
        at com.hazelcast.collection.impl.queue.QueueProxyImpl.remove(QueueProxyImpl.java:96)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are getting item.getItem() to be null. You are not allowed null in queue remove API. Can you put a control before remove to see what you are getting for the item.getItem()?